# Showing hyperlink URL and images in dialogflow response

Tags: dialogflow-es

Could anyone please help how to show active hyperlink for any web URL, so that once a user click on the URl it will open the required webpage.

Also, how to show image file i.e. jpeg, gif, bitmap image in the chatbot response.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dialogflow works with many different platforms, each of which might do this differently. Updating your question with the platforms/integrations you're trying to use and showing any code you've already written can help. StackOverflow works best when you've already tried something and are having problems, but can show us what you've tried. See [How do I ask a good question?][https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] for more about writing a question that can help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help...
Creating an image response

If the user asks what a cat looks like, you can send an image of a cat, which will get displayed on the user's phone.

The following code shows an image message object:

"image": { "imageUri": "http://myweb.com/cat.png" }”

Excerpt From: Henry Lee. “Voice User Interface Projects.” Apple Books. https://books.apple.com/us/book/voice-user-interface-projects/id1368882637